# One-to-many relationship mapping: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-key-relationship

I'm making my mapping of a simple database structure, but can't figure out what is wrong. I got a one to many relationship between Company and User. One company can have many users. In the database structure it is a non-identifing relationship and the companyID on the users side is optional (in my db and in my entity).

Here is my code:

### User Entity

```
public class User
    {
        public int userID { get; set; }
        public int? companyID { get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    }
```

### Company Entity

```
public class Company
{

    public int companyID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

### Mapping Context

```
   public class FreelauncherContext : DbContext
   {
    public IDbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        /*************USERS**************/
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(t => t.userID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("user", "freelauncher");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(t => t.companyID).HasColumnName("company_id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(t => t.Company).WithMany(t => t.Users).HasForeignKey(t => t.companyID); 
        /*************COMPANY**************/
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasKey(t => t.companyID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().ToTable("company", "freelauncher");
     }
```

As I don't see any mistakes here, I have been searching for errors in my database but i cannot find any...

Any suggestions please?

### Edit

When i remove the relationship and id related with the relationship and execute the insert, there are no errors and the insert is saved

Comment: I think, company table doesn't have record with null ID. As CompanyID is foreign key in User table.  Company ID entered in user table must be present in Comapny table

Comment: The relation between company and user isn't always necessary, so they have to be able to be null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the entity User the optional int of companyID, I changed that line to ==>

```
    public Nullable<int> companyID { get; set; }
```

I can't explain what difference it makes, but now it works perfectly

Comment: from your question: "companyID on the users side is optional " - an "optional `int`" is a nullable `int`, if it is just a plain not- nullable `int` then it is compulsory to have a value for it, therefore it is a compulsory foreign key.